# #Describe the smallest equivalence relation

Tags: real-analysis, relations

#### Describe the smallest equivalence relation on the set of real numbers which contains the line $x - y = 1$ in the $(x, y)$-plane.

#### My Answer:

$R=\text{locus}\{x-y=n|n\in \mathbb{Z} \} $

(I changed $\mathbb{N}$ to$\mathbb{Z}$, thanks to Fred.)

Is this the smallest equivalence relation? Need help!!

Comment: At least allow $x-y=z$ for any integer $z$ (not necessarily $z$ a natural number).

Comment: Note that when $x\sim y$ then $y\sim x$ must hold if $\sim$ is a equivalence relation (symmetry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $R$ be the smallest equivalence relation. Then $R$ is reflexive, hence for all $x \in \mathbb R$: $xRx$. But there is no $ n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x-x=n$.

Furthermore: if $xRy$ then $yRx$, but $x-y=-(y-x)$.

Therfore try:

$R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: \exists k \in \mathbb Z: x-y =k\}$.

Comment: Thanks, the negative part got out of my mind, anyway is the $R$ you defined smallest?

Comment: @MANMAID It can be shown Fred's definition (after "Therefore try") is indeed the smallest equivalence relation containing the line $x-y=1.$

Comment: Okk, understood, but can you(@coffeemath ) give me a hint how to prove the "smallest" part.

Comment: You can show this by proving that: for any fixed real $t,$ and for all integers $k,$ the relation $R$ contains the ordered pair $(t,t+k).$ To do the latter, first us induction to show it for all $k \ge 1.$ (also when $k=0$ that statement follows because $R$ is assumed reflexive.) Lastly use that $R$ is assumed to be reflexive.